# Javascript not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the page, there is a table list of users details. By clicking on the Edit Button, it enable the row of the content to be edited. The code below works on IE, but shows no response in Chrome. I need the site to be working both IE and chrome. Not sure the reason on why chrome is not giving any response.

```
<td style="display:none;" class="bb">
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Edit" style="width:40px;" 
        onclick="EnableUpdate(this.parentNode.parentNode);">
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Save" style="display:none;width:40px;" 
        onclick="SaveUpdate(this.parentNode.parentNode);">
</td>
```

---

```
function EnableUpdate(oThisRow){
  DeactivateCurrentRow(oThisRow);
  var oCellsOfThisRow = oThisRow.childNodes;
  var i, oGroup

  oGroup = oCellsOfThisRow(4).lastChild;
  oGroup.options.length=0;
  for (i = 0; i< GroupID.length; i++)
  {
        oGroup.options[i]=new Option(GroupID[i], GroupID[i]);
        if(oGroup.previousSibling.innerText == GroupID[i])
        oGroup.selectedIndex=i;
  }  

  for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
    oCellsOfThisRow(i).lastChild.value = oCellsOfThisRow(i).firstChild.innerText;

  for(i =1;i<7;i++) {
    oCellsOfThisRow(i).firstChild.style.display = "none";
    oCellsOfThisRow(i).firstChild.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: What does `console.log(oThisRow)` show?

Comment: What are all the functions for, there are several calls to custom functions?

Comment: How are you clicking on the button if the `<td>` has style `display: none`?

Comment: Where is `GroupID` defined?

Comment: Also, `oCellsOfThisRow` is not a function so you can't call it like `oCellsOfThisRow(i)`. You probably meant `oCellsOfThisRow[i]`

Comment: @Baramar - the Edit button doesn't have `display:none` and, if things worked right, would change the Save button to `display:block` (`firstChild.nextSibling.style.display = "block"`)

Comment: consol log Uncaught TypeError: oCellsOfThisRow is not a function

Comment: But the `<td>` the button is inside clearly has `display:none` in the posted code, making the button invisible

Comment: @Daiki see my comment above ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471208/javascript-not-working-on-chrome#comment58637936_35471208

Comment: @Phil - well, actually in older IE you could access a nodeList with parentheses, so that could be the error that makes it not work in Chrome, as it's generally invalid outside IE.

Comment: @adeneo yes, I'd say that's definitely the case

Comment: my IE version is IE 11, it works in IE

Comment: Good for you, and did you try what Phil is saying, changing it to `oCellsOfThisRow[i]`

Comment: changed for the function, still getting the same error

Comment: And you checked the console (F12) in Chrome for errors

Comment: getting different now Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: So `oCellsOfThisRow[i].firstChild.nextSibling` does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you load your code, but if you load it with document onload, then this won't work, because first the DOM is created an the scope for the onclick code is set at a time where the function is unknown.

```
window.onload = function(){
   function EnableUpdate(...){....};
}
```

This can easily happen if you use jquery and put all of your code in this

```
$(function(){});
```

So don't use the onclick attribute, instead use

`myElement.addEventListener('click',EnableUpdate);`

also in the onload function

Comment: If you are saying that *EnableUpdate* must be defined as a function when the related HTML is parsed into the DOM, then that is wrong. Inline listeners are evaluated each time an event occurs, so as long as *EnableUpdate* exists when the click event occurs, it will be called. If it didn't work that way, "bottom loading" scripts would not be so popular.

Comment: You are right, my post is a little mistakable. I will add an example.